# How to set .bash_profile, if it does not exist yet. I want to launch sublime from a command line in Mac

Tags: macos

I want to launch sublime from a command line in Mac, using `subl filename`. It seems to involve dealing with `.bash_profile`. But I didn't locate the file. What steps to be taken?

Answer (score 75):

A typical install of OS X won't create a `.bash_profile` for you. When you want to run functions from your command line, this is a must-have.

1. Start up Terminal
2. Type `cd ~/` to go to your home folder
3. Type `touch .bash_profile` to create your new file.
4. Edit `.bash_profile` with your favorite editor (or you can just type `open -e .bash_profile` to open it in TextEdit.
5. Type `. .bash_profile` to reload `.bash_profile` and update any functions you add. Notice the space between the two dots!

Comment: i'm on Mojave, this is not working. can you update you answer?.

Comment: It's working on Mojave, could you explain which step isn't working with you? @Vats

Answer (score 8):

**Update**
I'm on Mac OS Mojave.

Open `Terminal.app` and paste bellow line,

```
(1) touch .bash_profile
(2) open -a TextEdit.app .bash_profile
```

this will open a blank page in `TextEdit.app` , from here you can `add,update,delete` code.

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 3):

**Q1. How to check if `.bash_profile` exists or not in my mac?**

**Solution**: If you're using macOS 10.14 (Mojave) or below. Then open the Terminal.app. Run the following command to check if the `.bash_profile` exists or not in your mac.

```
if [ -r ~/.bash_profile ];
    then
        echo "Yes, file exists"
    else
        echo "No, file does not exists"
fi
```

After running the above command if you get the following line - "**Yes, file exists**" printed in your Terminal.app. That means the file exists in your mac.

If you get the following line - "No, file does not exist" printed in your Terminal.app. That means the file does not exist in your mac.

To create a `.bash_profile` file in your mac. Run the following command,

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
```

To restrict access to the `.bash_profile`. Run the following command,

```
chmod 700 ~/.bash_profile
```

**Q2. I want to launch sublime from a command line in Mac?**

**Solution**: To launch sublime from mac. You can make a symlink to `subl`. Assuming you've placed **Sublime Text** in the **Applications** folder, and that you have a `~/bin` directory in your path, you can run the following command:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

For more details [visit the official sublime documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html)

Answer (score 2):

just create a new file - it doesn't come default with your computer. all under your user directory - ex. /Users/username

```
touch .bash_profile
~/.bash_profile
```