# Change PHP version used by Composer on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, composer-php, wamp

I have already use WAMP 2.5 with PHP 5.5.12, and with Composer.
The php is on:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12
```

For new project, I need to use nginx and installed PHP 7.
The php is on:

```
C:\nginx\php
```

Now, using GitBash MINGW32, I tried to install laravel 5.3 using Composer `create-project` but it said

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.3 in a version 
installable using your PHP version 5.5.12.
```

I already put both `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12` and `C:\nginx\php` on Windows System PATH variable.

How do I change the PHP version used by Composer?

Comment: Quite simply never put any PHP folder on the windows PATH when using WAMPServer. As WAMPServer can contain 20 versions of PHP, if you put things on the PATH you destroy the ability to switch PHP versions simply by using the wampmanager menus

Comment: You mean I should just install another PHP version on WAMPServer? But would host the web running the PHP on Nginx using PHP installed on WAMPServer works?

Comment: No thats not what I ment to say

Comment: So am I right to say that, that's for the case when I host on WAMPServer only?

Comment: Yes I think so, but now I am a little confused

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three ways to do this, really.

### Create an alias in `.bashrc` to always run composer with the corresponding version

Something like `` alias ncomposer=`/path/to/php /path/to/composer.phar ` ``

### Specify the path to PHP version inside `composer.phar` itself

This is specified at the start of the file: `#!/path/to/php php`. Then composer should run with `composer.phar`

**NB!** The line will disappear upon self-update, so it's not a reliable solution.

### Move up the path with the newest PHP version

If you place `C:\nginx\php` first, it should be used by default when using composer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Although this question was solved, the answer didn't help me. I will explain how I managed to make [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to work in a version of PHP different from the one which is installed by default on my OS (PHP 7.1.1) as well as in my environment variables (these will not be changed !). Note that I'm using Xampp, but the principle remains the same for Wamp.

- Starting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41709096/3452348) :

  1. Start up Git Bash
  2. Type `cd ~/` to go to your home folder
  3. Type `touch .bash_profile` to create your new file.
  4. Edit `.bash_profile` with your favorite editor

---

- In my case I have a folder named `php733` inside xampp folder which corresponds to PHP 7.3.3. This is [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46986206/3452348) that helped me in creating the alias :

  ```
  alias composer733='/c/[xampp folder]/php733/php.exe /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar '
  ```

  Then, type `. .bash_profile` to reload `.bash_profile` and update any functions you add. **Notice the space between the two dots** !

---

Finally, type this command in Git Bash :

```
composer733 [whatever you wan]
```

---

**Example** : in the project that requires at least PHP 7.1.3

1. Using **composer** :

   ```
   $ composer update
   This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement.
   ```
2. Using **composer733** (the alias I created) :

   ```
   $ composer733 update
   Loading composer repositories with package information
   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
   Package operations: 98 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
     - Installing [...] (v1.11.0): Loading from cache
   ```

**It works, without having to change the environment variables**

Comment: Add `alias php733='/c/[xampp folder]/php733/php.exe'` to use `php733` in your terminal

Answer (score 1):

Or you can write something like this (in cmd):

```
> c:\wamp\htdocs\my-project> C:\wamp\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64\php.exe 
"C:\Program Files\Composer\composer.phar" install
```