# Composer Downgrade php version 7.1 to 7.0 on windows

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I am working on Laravel project where one of its packages require PHP 7.0 version. Currently, I have installed latest version but now I want to downgrade it to 7.0. How should I do this?  Is it possible with command line or do I need to change PHP files manually? I tried to find  this topic on google also on StackOverflow but can't find any solution for this problem

I found one solution here but unable to implement that

[here is the link I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881924/change-php-version-used-by-composer-on-windows/39882429#39882429)

This is the error I get with 7.1 version

> Function mcrypt_module_open() is deprecated

Comment: It might be better to check if there is a newer version of the package generating this error.  Going back to an older version of PHP probably isn't what you want in the longer term.  Also is this an error, or just a warning?  If it's a warning, you can probably ignore it until the package you are depending on gets a new release

Comment: I am using latest version of package..and its a error not warning