# having problem installing Jetstream and livewire in my newly installed laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

dev,

please has anyone came across this kinda issue, I was installing new laravel 8 and hope to install  [jet-stream and livewire][1]  together with  it,  I installed laravel 8 with  the following cmd:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

then proceed to install jet-stream with

```
$ composer require laravel/jetstream
```

this cmd result :

---

The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2019%2427b76b9f0218e7440cf8a7d3dfe11f6ac69610e72f5277d4ee2bf31e24c43772.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
http://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

**[InvalidArgumentException]
Package laravel/jetstream at version  has a PHP requirement incompatible wi
th your PHP version (7.2.32)**

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

---

i run

```
php -v
```

and here is my php version :

---

PHP 7.2.32 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2020 10:38:05) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x6
4 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

---

I have tried updating my PHP version through cm for a composer with
:

```
$ composer config platform.php 7.4.3
```

and tried run

```
$ composer require laravel/jetstream
```

this then results :

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - laravel/jetstream 1.x-dev requires illuminate/support ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0].
    - laravel/jetstream v1.3.0 requires illuminate/support ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0].
    - laravel/jetstream v1.3.1 requires illuminate/support ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0].
    - laravel/jetstream v1.3.2 requires illuminate/support ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0].
    - don't install illuminate/support 8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - don't install illuminate/support v8.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.28.3
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.28.3, required as ^7.24) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.28.3].
    - Installation request for laravel/jetstream ^1.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/jetstream[1.x-dev, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

here is my composer.json

---

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.24",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.4.3"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

---

please the problem seems visual that I needed to upgrade my PHP version but I don't know where to

please guide , thanks
[1]: https://jetstream.laravel.com/

Comment: welcome to SO ... `laravel/jetstream` you cannot use in `laravel 7` for that you need `laravel 8`

Comment: @KamleshPaul  thank you for replying, do you mean I have not yet installed laravel 8 with composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog  ?  this project was installed today

Comment: in your composer.json `"laravel/framework": "^7.24"` check

Comment: What have you tried to resolve all these errors? Anything? Which parts are unclear?

Comment: do you mean i should remove "laravel/framework": "^7.24", ? because is currently present in composer.json

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried run this: $ composer config platform.php 7.4.3  to upgrade my PHP version but still not work, please what do you suggest?

Comment: `composer config platform.php 7.4.3` does not update your PHP version. It only instructs Composer to resolve dependencies specific to this version. If Jetstream is not compatible with Laravel 7, you have to start with updating Laravel to v8

Comment: what I was trying to say was that I installed laravel today and I think the latest version would have been installed or not? do I need to select? I believe the  laravel create-project command create the latest version of laravel as at the time .... please enlight

Comment: As you can see in your `composer.json`, you have required `"laravel/framework": "^7.24"`. This does not include v8 of Laravel

Comment: @NicoHaase so should I remove it

Comment: That's something you have to decide. `laravel/framework` is a pretty important package if you are implementing a  Laravel application

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that information is lacking.
but...
in my case.!

```
composer global remove laravel / installer
composer global remove laravel / laravel **
```

and

```
composer global require laravel / installer

php -v
```

> PHP 7.4.19 (cli) (built: May 4 2021 11:06:37) (NTS) Copyright (c) The
> PHP Group Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v7.4.19, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

there you can use`

```
composer global config platform.php 7.4.19
```

to configure the composer globally with your php version

now.
I use jetstream

```
laravel new minimarket --git -f --jet
```

For this method install clean you laravel 8, i use Fedora 34 and maria database

Answer (score -1):

Please check  Laravel 8 need PHP 7.3 or above (You are getting issue because you are using  php7.2 )

Please check the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x

Comment: thank you I knew, but I looking for how to upgrade my PHP version to meet this needs

Comment: you  are using xampp or lampp ?

Comment: i am using xampp server

Comment: these are the steps how to upgrade php vesion in xampp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154762/upgrading-php-in-xampp-for-windows

or 

you can install xampp latest version , in latest version php 7.4 is already

Comment: do you mean my xampp PHP version can laravel project and in composer?

Comment: no i am not saying this ,  i mean if you download  and install latest version of xampp , then there will be no compatibility issue

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. According to the `composer.json`, the OP is not using Laravel 8 after all

Comment: A workaround to Lafit Kumar comment : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56407089/3452348