# react-native not found + mac os

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, react-native

I am trying to run basic react-native app in my macOS. I installed node through brew .

```
My node version: v6.12.0
npm version :5.5.1
```

Then i installed reatc-native-cli using npm. Now when i try to create a project using `react-native init` it says `react-native command not found`.

I tried all solutions but no hope. as i am new bee to this react-native guide me solve this. Thanks in advance.

I tried all post including

[react-native: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189081/react-native-command-not-found)

Comment: What was the command used to install it? Did you use `npm install -g` and did it succeed without errors?

Comment: Isn't React Native project create `create-react-native-app <name>`?

Comment: Using appropriate version of npm will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You should install **React-Native CLI** first before using **"react-native init"**.

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

For more information of getting started **React-Native** in manual, please follow this [Document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

> And select tab **Building Projects with Native Code** for manual create project without **Expo**

Comment: The question literally said "Then i installed react-native-cli using npm". Did you even read it

Answer (score 3):

#### Steps to install React Native CLI in Mac OS:

1. Run `npm install -g react-native-cli`

> or `sudo npm install -g react-native-cli`
> 2. Once successful, get the installed path from the output:

```
/Users/jeemok/.npm-packages/bin/react-native -> /Users/jeemok/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
+ react-native-cli@2.0.1
added 78 packages from 28 contributors in 12.39s
```

> In my case, my path is `/Users/jeemok/.npm-packages/bin/react-native`
> 3. Run `export PATH="/Users/jeemok/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"`
> 4. Now you should be able to use the command `react-native`

---

#### Example to init a project

```
react-native init TodoApp
cd TodoApp
react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 0):

1.install
 -Xcode 
 -Android Studio
2.
react-native init FirstApp

3. if hit the below error
   -bash:react-native:command not found

4.
npm list -g | head -n 1 
5. 
/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.1.4/lib 
U will found the file "react native"
 
6.
open .bash_profile (if .bash_profile not exist [setup .bash_profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037537/how-to-set-bash-profile-if-it-does-not-exist-yet-i-want-to-launch-sublime-fro))
add the below in .bash_profile file
export PATH=”/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.1.4/bin:$PATH”

7. run the command to reload .bash_profile
   source .bash_profile

8.create your project
react-native init FirstApp

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this issue.

1. Call `npm list -g | head -n 1`
2. Open .bash_profile in a code editor. It should be located at `~/.bash_profile`
3. Paste `export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.12.0/bin:${PATH}"` somewhere in it. Make sure you have the correct version in there. Also make sure PATH is wrapped in { }
4. Save the file.
5. Close your terminal and reopen. You should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this not found issue. For those who are still facing the issue, I am sharing my solution.
I have setup a fresh react native project by running the following command.

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

we don't need to install

> react-native-cli
>
> If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues.

as mentioned in the original docs.

just add npx at beginning `npx react native link` and it worked!